# RegionPlot after Reduce

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a problem in this form

[image]

To solve this I have tried this

```
f1[y_] := 2 - (y - 1)^2;
f2[x_, y_] := x + 1 - (y - 2)^2;
f[x_, y_] := Max[f1[y], f2[x, y]];
```

The line below then seems to solve the problem:

```
Reduce[f[x, y] >= f[x, Interval[0, 4]], {x, y}, Reals]
```

My question is, is this the right procedure to treat the problem? And if so, then how to plot this region?

Comment: `RegionPlot[ Evaluate@Reduce[f[x, y] >= f[x, Interval[0, 4]], {x, y}, 
   Reals], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]` or `expr = Reduce[f[x, y] >= f[x, Interval[0, 4]], {x, y},  Reals]; RegionPlot[expr, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First our definitions:

```
f[x_, y_] := Max[2 - (y - 1)^2, x + 1 - (y - 2)^2]
Γ = Interval[{0, 4}]
```

The definition of $G(x)$ is (adjusting the notation slightly):

$$
\{y\in\Gamma:\forall_{z\in\Gamma}f(x,y)\geq f(x,z)\}
$$

In English, this is

> The set of $y$ (in $\Gamma$) for which $f(x,y)$ is no less than $f(x,z)$ for *any* $z$ in $\Gamma$.

We can make (most of) this statement in Mathematica:

```
ForAll[z, z ∈ Interval[{0, 4}], f[x, y] >= f[x, z]]
Reduce[%]
(* (y == 1 && x <= 1) || (y == 2 && x >= 1) *)
```

(This seems not to work in Mathematica 9, but an alternate and equivalent formulation exists:)

```
ForAll[z, 0 <= z <= 4, f[x, y] >= f[x, z]]
Reduce[%]
(* (y == 1 && x <= 1) || (y == 2 && x >= 1) *)
```

This is actually a different solution that what you came up with.  It implies:

$$
G(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\{1\}&x<1 \\ \{1,2\}&x=1 \\ \{2\}&x>1\end{array}\right.
$$

We can plot this like so:

```
soln = Solve[%, y]
Plot[Evaluate[y /. soln], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

As for why this is the behavior, we can make an easy little `Manipulate` to explore the solution:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{f[x, y], f[x, z]}, {z, 0, 4}], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Note that what the problem is really asking is for the values of $y$ that maximize $f(x,y)$.  We can see that $f$ has two local maxima, the peaks of the two parabolas.  As $x$ changes, one moves up and the other moves down, but they don't shift left and right.  Therefore $y$ that maximizes $f$ will stay at the location of the first peak until the peaks are equal, then it will switch to the location of the second peak.

Comment: I receive an error:
Reduce@ForAll[z, Element[z, \[CapitalGamma]], f[x, y] >= f[x, z]]

Gives

Reduce::naqs4(*blah blah*) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities

Comment: I defined $\Gamma$, did you copy that part?  (Or just replace it with `Interval[{0,4}]`)

Comment: I did that.... And I even did the replacement but still the same problem!!

Comment: @Morry What version are you using?  And what is the result of `ForAll` before the `Reduce`?

Comment: https://db.tt/FIHpbOGb
Mathematica 9

Comment: @Morry I don't think this changed from 9, weird.  Try `Resolve` instead of `Reduce`?

Comment: Still the same problem....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23084/discussion-between-2012rcampion-and-morry).

Comment: Can you help me to solve it for another setup?

Comment: @Morry I'm back in the chat

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is the right thing to do, but here's my approach:

```
red = Reduce[f[x, y] >= f[x, Interval[0, 4]], {x, y}]
```

(*
(x <= 0 && 0 <= y <= 2) || (0 < x < 4 && 
   0 <= y <= 2 + Sqrt[x]) || (x >= 4 && 0 <= y <= 4)
*)

For a first idea what's going on:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

And finally RegionPlot to show a plot in which **red** is True:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@red, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]